# How to add a new column with random chars to pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to add new column with a random 8 char string to every row of Spark Data Frame.

Function to generate 8 char string -

```
def id(size=8, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

My Spark DF -

```
columns = ["Seqno","Name"]
data = [("1", "john jones"),
    ("2", "tracey smith"),
    ("3", "amy sanders")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)

df = df.withColumn("randomid", lit(id()))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

But with above code, random id is being duplicated. Any pointers on it to get it unique for each row?

```
+-----+------------+--------------------------------+
|Seqno|Name        |randomid                        |
+-----+------------+--------------------------------+
|1    |john jones  |uz6iugmraripznyzizt1ymvbs8gi2qv8|
|2    |tracey smith|uz6iugmraripznyzizt1ymvbs8gi2qv8|
|3    |amy sanders |uz6iugmraripznyzizt1ymvbs8gi2qv8|
+-----+------------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `uuid` function to generate a string, and then replace the `-` in it.

```
df = df.withColumn("randomid", F.expr('replace(uuid(), "-", "")'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuffle` transformation:

```
import string
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
source_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("1", "john jones"),
    ("2", "tracey smith"),
    ("3", "amy sanders")
], ['Seqno', 'Name'])

df = (df
      .withColumn('source_characters', f.split(f.lit(source_characters), ''))
      .withColumn('random_string', f.concat_ws('', f.slice(f.shuffle(f.col('source_characters')), 1, 8)))
      .drop('source_characters')
)

df.show()
```

and output looks like:

```
+-----+------------+-------------+                                              
|Seqno|        Name|random_string|
+-----+------------+-------------+
|    1|  john jones|     f8yWABgY|
|    2|tracey smith|     Xp6idNb7|
|    3| amy sanders|     zU8aSN4C|
+-----+------------+-------------+
```